Is there a convenient way to create nested JSON in Delphi?
I'm creating a nested JSON object in Delphi using this code:
   var jo:TJsonObject;

   try
      jo := TJsonObject.Create;

      jo.AddPair('data', TJsonObject.Create);
      with jo.GetValue<TJsonObject>('data') do begin
         AddPair('details', TJSONObject.Create);
         with jo.GetValue<TJsonObject>('details') do begin
            AddPair('foo', 'bar');
         end;
      end;

   finally
      FreeAndNil(jo);
   end;

It works and produces the expected result:
{
  "data": {
    "details": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  }
}           


It's not too ugly, but I'm wondering if there is a nicer way to structure the code so I don't have to first add each child object and then look it up on the next line using GetValue?

While I've done this before in python, I'm not confident in Delphi.  Have you tried a recursive function all the while passing the next level as a parameter?

Yes, there are cleaner ways to do that, but your code is putting all nested objects under initial object. What is your expected JSON output?

@DalijaPrasnikar I've updated the question with the expected JSON. The code works as intended, but it seems a bit clumpsy and inefficient to first add a child object and then look it up. Of course I could create separate variables for each child object, which would be more effective but add more bloat and IMHO look less intuitive.

The with clauses look pretty useless to me. I also doubt that the shown code produces the shown result.

I hate to disappoint you, but your code does not produce the JSON you expect. I get this  {"data":{},"details":{},"foo":"bar"}

Maybe consider using SuperObject - I found it to be way more easier to use than the Delphi built in.

The corrected code using with that would produce appropriate result would be: jo.AddPair('data', TJsonObject.Create);       with jo.GetValue<TJsonObject>('data') do begin          AddPair('details', TJSONObject.Create);          with GetValue<TJsonObject>('details') do begin             AddPair('foo', 'bar');          end;       end;

Using Delphi's built-in TJSONObject framework, the only way to avoid having to lookup a nested object after adding it to the document is to simply not add it to the document until after it has been populated, eg:
var
  jo, joData, joDetails: TJsonObject;

jo := TJsonObject.Create;
try
  joDetails := TJSONObject.Create;
  joDetails.AddPair('foo', 'bar');

  joData := TJsonObject.Create;
  joData.AddPair('details', joDetails);

  jo.AddPair('data', joData);

  // use Jo as needed...

finally
  jo.Free;
end;

That being said, you might consider using TJSONObjectBuilder instead. It's a bit uglier on the setup and cleanup, but it gives you a more natural interface for building up the document sequentially, eg:
var
  Builder: TJSONObjectBuilder;
  Writer: TJsonTextWriter;
  StringWriter: TStringWriter;
  StringBuilder: TStringBuilder;

StringBuilder := TStringBuilder.Create;
StringWriter := TStringWriter.Create(StringBuilder);
Writer := TJsonTextWriter.Create(StringWriter);
Writer.Formatting := TJsonFormatting.Indented;
Builder := TJSONObjectBuilder.Create(Writer);

try
  Builder
    .BeginObject
      .BeginObject('data')
        .BeginObject('details')
          .Add('foo','bar')
        .EndObject
      .EndObject
    .EndObject;

  // use StringBuilder.ToString as needed...
finally
  Builder.Free;
  Writer.Free;
  StringWriter.Free;
  StringBuilder.Free;
end;



A nice example on how unbound code indention can be used in a meaningful way (in contrast to f.e. Python, where indention is part of the syntax). For newcomers: method chaining is possible when all the methods always return their own class instance - the whole design came with fluent interfaces (and has its drawbacks).

I'd recommend using the XSuperObject library for handling JSON (https://github.com/onryldz/x-superobject) , I use it for any projects I'm working on that involve manipulating JSON because I find it requires much less boiler plate code than the built in Delphi JSON libraries. The documentation on the respository gives an overview of how to use the library to create complex JSON structures.

Can you show how to nest the JSON with XSuperObject?
